# Animate alpha of letters in a UITextView with different delays

Tags: objective-c

I want to fade in (alpha 0.0 to alpha 1.0) characters of a UITextView with a constant 0.25 second duration but with different delays (0,0.25,0.5, and 0.75). Which delay a character gets would be randomly determined with an arc4random() function call.

I am very familiar with performing animations on entire views, e.g. using this method:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Also familiar with keyframe animations, where you can apply different animations and delays to different keyframes, using this method:

```
+ (void)animateKeyframesWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

But I am at a loss for a good approach to applying different animations to letters within a single UITextView.

Not looking for someone to write the code for me but would love some direction on how to start solving the problem.

Thanks!

**Edit #2**
I am successfully animating a single CATextLayer.  Moving on to try multiple CATextLayers as suggested by Abhi.

Comment: Have you looked at using NSAttributedString? It allows you to modify the color of individual ranges of the string, not sure if it's animatable or not though

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with `UITextView`.

Instead, you should create a `UIView` with `CATextLayer` objects inside.

Each run of characters you want to animate separately must be inside it's own `CATextLayer` object.

Text layer objects are created like so:

```
static CGFloat layerContentsScale; // will be set to 1.0 or 2.0, depending whether the hardware has a retina screen or not

@implementation MyUIViewSubclass

+ (void)initialize
{
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    layerContentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]; // [UIScreen mainScreen] is extremely slow, so we don't want to do it very often.
  });
}

- (void)updateTextLayers // call this at some point, maybe when you apply the text value
{
  NSString *string = @"hello";
  UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
  CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];

  CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
  textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, stringSize.width, self.frame.size.height);
  textLayer.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)markerSpeed];
  textLayer.contentsScale = layerContentsScale;
  textLayer.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef)font;
  textLayer.fontSize = font.pointSize;
  textLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

  [self.layer addSublayer:textLayer];
}
```

Then you can apply animations to the text layer in a variety of ways. Opacity, position, size, 3D transforms, etc. A `CATextLayer` will render the text in pixels and store them in the GPU, ready to be animated in any way you want.

Keep in mind, unlike with UIView all transformations to a layer are animated by default. Sometimes this can conflict when you try to add your own animations on top. This includes changing the text, which will do a cross fade.

Here's an example of changing the text with no cross fade animation, and then fading the text in:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0];
textLayer.string = @"foo";
[CATransaction commit];

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:2];
textLayer.opacity = 1;
[CATransaction commit];
```